# Does AWS Bitnami stay up to date?

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitnami

I use a Bitnami NodeJS instance on AWS. I found in the Bitnami docs](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/get-started-lightsail/) that I have to manually keep a Wordpress installation updated. But for the OS, I could not find whether it keeps itself updated or if I need to update packages and the distribution updated by manually running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` periodically. Does anyone know and can provide a reference?

Comment: I would log in and run the updates. If there's a lot of them to apply then it's not applying them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here,

we build and install the packages from scratch, do not use the system packages to install the web server or the runtime in your machine. Using the apt commands will update the rest of packages in the system (ssh, openssl, and
other libraries) but will not update the Apache's, Node.js' or PHP's version.

Please note that we do not run the apt command for you, if there is any new version of those packages, you will need to run the apt command and install them.

In case you want to update the Apache's or PHP's version, you will need to launch a new instance that contains the latest versions of those components and migrate your data to that new one.

Comment: Right, I only installed MongoDB using the system packages. So if I run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and `npm audit fix` periodically, the machine will be up to date, right?

Comment: Correct, you will update the system packages and the npm modules of your application but won't update Node.js or Apache.